# Oracle PL/SQL - How do i copy a large amount of data from one table to another using oracle collections

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

This is part of an assignment to test the processing speed of each oracle collection (associative array, variable array, and nested tables), but i'm unsure how to approach this - i'm fairly new to PL/SQL and oracle in general.

So i have two tables created - one contains three columns, with over 3 million records, the other is empty. How do i copy the data from the filled table to the empty one using the collection method?

Thanks in advance - please excuse me if i did not provide enough information - i'm fairly new to this...

Richard

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. While your question is currently too broad to be answered objectively (Take a Look at [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)) you should start by researching [Bulk Collection & FORALL INSERT](http://psoug.org/reference/array_processing.html), once you have further narrowed you question I'm sure that this website will be more useful.

Comment: Why not use `insert into .. select ...` instead? That will be *much* faster than any bulk operation in PL/SQL.

Comment: It's better to use: create table as select * from table

Comment: As @a_horse_with_no_name says: `insert into .. select ...` is the quickest way to go. Add to that the `append` hint and the `nologging` clause understanding the associated issues with recoverability. Also, add indexes to the table after the insert is completed, not before the copy. Using a collection means reading a batch of data, context switches to plsql, writing back again, etc. Unless there is some significant transformation and logging you need to do, I don't think you want to use a collection.

Comment: Just to point it out, while the pure SQL solutions are indeed more performatic I think that the OP is trying to benchmark the three types of PL/SQL collections.

Comment: Thank you, all. @ Anthony, I am indeed attempting to benchmark the three collection type, but I will do further research and refine my query. Thanks again!

Comment: If you're trying to benchmark different PL/SQL collections, don't use a table to test them - your test results will be swamped by the time required to read and write the data. Instead, generate the data using PL/SQL (e.g. a simple number, or padded strings, or whatever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* package header */
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE perfrormance_test AS

    PROCEDURE nested_table;
    PROCEDURE associative_array;

END perfrormance_test;


/* package body */
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY perfrormance_test AS

    PROCEDURE nested_table
    AS
        /* select all records from source table */
        CURSOR big_table_cur IS
            SELECT  col1
            ,       col2
            ,       col3
            FROM    big_table;

        /* create nested table type and variable that will hold BIG_TABLE's records */
        TYPE big_table_ntt IS TABLE OF big_table_cur%ROWTYPE;
        l_big_table  big_table_ntt;
    BEGIN
        /* open pointer to SELECT statement */
        OPEN  big_table_cur;
        /* collect data in the collection */
        FETCH big_table_cur BULK COLLECT INTO l_big_table;
        /* close the pointer */
        CLOSE big_table_cur;

        /* print size of the collection */
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Nested table holds: ' || TO_CHAR(l_big_table.COUNT) || ' records.');

        /* write data down to target table */
        FORALL indx IN l_big_table.FIRST..l_big_table.LAST
            INSERT  INTO big_table_target(col1, col2, col3)
            VALUES  (l_big_table(indx).col1, l_big_table(indx).col2, l_big_table(indx).col3);
        /*
        **  or you can use it this way:
        **
        **  VALUES  (l_big_table(indx));
        */

        /* print number of rows inserted */
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of rows inserted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows');

        /* save changes */
        COMMIT;

        /* or if you want undo changes  */
        /* ROLLBACK; */
    END nested_table;

    PROCEDURE associative_array
    AS
        /* create record (row) type */
        TYPE strings_rec IS RECORD
        (
            one   VARCHAR2(4000)
        ,   two   VARCHAR2(4000)
        ,   three VARCHAR2(4000)
        );

        /* create collection of records: type and variable */
        TYPE strings_aat IS TABLE OF strings_rec INDEX BY VARCHAR2(4000);
        l_strings  strings_aat;
    BEGIN
        /* populate collection with 3 000 000 rows */
        /* looping can take some time */
        FOR indx IN 1..3000000 LOOP
            l_strings('indx_' || TO_CHAR(indx)).one   := 'column one   indx ' || TO_CHAR(indx);
            l_strings('indx_' || TO_CHAR(indx)).two   := 'column two   indx ' || TO_CHAR(indx);
            l_strings('indx_' || TO_CHAR(indx)).three := 'column three indx ' || TO_CHAR(indx);
        END LOOP;

        /* print size of the collection */
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Assoc table holds: ' || TO_CHAR(l_strings.COUNT) || ' records.');

        /*
        ** CREATE TABLE aat_target
        ** (
        **     t_id  VARCHAR(4000)
        ** ,   one   VARCHAR(4000)
        ** ,   two   VARCHAR(4000)
        ** ,   three VARCHAR(4000)
        ** );
        */

        /* insert rows */
        FORALL indx IN l_strings.FIRST..l_strings.LAST
            INSERT  INTO aat_target(t_id, one, two, three)
            VALUES  (l_strings(indx), l_strings(indx).one, l_strings(indx).two, l_strings(indx).three);

        /* print number of rows inserted */
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of rows inserted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows');

        COMMIT;
    END associative_array;

END perfrormance_test;
```

Run SQL*PLUS from command line:

```
sqlplus user/pass@db_name
```

Type:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> SET TIMING ON
SQL> BEGIN
2    perfrormance_test.nested_table;
3    END;
-- exec time will be displayed here

SQL> BEGIN
2    perfrormance_test.associative_array;
3    END;
-- exec time will be displayed here
```

It is not tested so you will have to correct small typos.

I do no use VARRAY.

Comment: Thank you so much, i created separate procedures out of each methods and used an anonymous block containing dbms_utility.get_time to get the execution time. Thanks again, slk - your god among men!

Comment: Np problem. That is the fastest way to work with collections (BULK collect and BULK DML). Other useful hint: It is good to run SQL from PL/SQL but not other way around. Good luck.